# Importing CSV file from FTP on WooCommerce based store

Tags: wordpress, csv, woocommerce, ftp

im trying to build a shop that will take all the products from CSV. This is not so difficult but for easy changes and access from more people, we will share the CSV on ftp.

I need a plugin or system for WooCommerce that can get every day the CSV file from FTP server and update the already uploaded from first time import CSV file.

I found out this plugin - https://www.webtoffee.com/product/product-import-export-woocommerce/

But dunno if its fit my need and not so rich to just buy it and tested.

Can you help me with some suggestions or tips for this plugin or other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this plugin successfully. Also it has a [basic version here.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/)

But no FTP option in basic version. The Pro version is able to get every day the CSV file from FTP server and update.

Here is the link to the [setup article.](https://www.webtoffee.com/setting-up-cron-job-for-woocommerce-product-import-and-export/)